# outlook web addin using icon(logo) only visible through web but not on desktop outlook client. How to make it visible on the outlook client?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Developed an outlook web addin using VS 2022, used custom icon which is only visible through web but not on desktop outlook client. How to make it visible on the outlook client?

any idea or solutions are welcome, thanks

manifest Icon code:

```
<IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon64.png"/>
```

I have tried changing it, clearing cache, re publish & redeploy locally Everything works when I run it in chrome, The icon and ribbon changes in browser but it is not reflecting in desktop outlook client

Comment: The image specified in the IconUrl is not the one that gets displayed in the buttons in the Outlook Ribbon. The IconUrl is displayed when viewing your list of installed add-ins in the Get-AddIns UI. The image displayed in the ribbon is the <Icon> element specified as a child of the <Control> element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the absolute full URL in the manifest.

The [IconUrl element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/iconurl?view=excel-js-preview) allows specifying the full, absolute URL of the image that is used to represent your Office Add-in in the insertion UX, AppSource, and the vertical task pane tab bar.

I can confirm that it works on my side in outlook desktop. Try clearing the browser and application cache, see [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, Like this?
 <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:44341/Images/icon64.png"/>
this is not working either

Comment: Don't forget the protocol part, for example, in samples I see something like that - `<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/logo.png"/>`

Comment: yeah, I have added like this only still not working in outlook desktop but in chrome it is. I think while adding comment here it got pasted as hyperlink that's why protocol is not showing up here

Comment: That works on my side in outlook desktop. Try clearing the browser and application cache, see [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) for more information.